# How to generalize a JMockit test using Spring autowiring

Tags: jmockit

So I would like to use a generic test for a few different Dao methods.  Inside the Dao, I implemented the save functionality to be Entity independent, so I figured it would be best to make the tests Entity independent as well.  Currently I have the following for one of my [jmockit](/questions/tagged/jmockit) tests that is autowired with [spring](/questions/tagged/spring).

```java
@Injectable
public EntityManager em;

@Tested
SyncClaimDao syncClaimDao = new SyncClaimDaoImpl();

@Before
public void setUp() {
    Deencapsulation.setField(syncClaimDao, "em", em);
}

private void testSaveEntity (Class T) {
    // Existing claim happy path
    new Expectations() {
        {
            em.contains(any); result = true;
            em.merge(any);
        }
    };

    if (T.isInstance(SyncClaimEntity.class)) {
        Assert.assertTrue(syncClaimDao.saveClaim(new SyncClaimEntity()));
    } else if (...) {...}
}

@Test
public void testSaveClaim() {
    testSaveEntity(SyncClaimEntity.class);
}
```

SyncClaimDaoImpl

```java
@Override
public boolean saveClaim(SyncClaimEntity claim) {
    return saveEntity(claim);
}

private boolean saveEntity(Object entity) {
    boolean isPersisted = false;

    try {
        isPersisted = em.contains(entity);

        if (isPersisted) {
            em.merge(entity);
        } else {
            em.persist(entity);
            em.flush();
            isPersisted = true;
        }
        logger.debug("Persisting " + entity.getClass().getSimpleName() + ": " + entity.toString());
    }
    catch (NullPointerException ex) {
        ...
    }
    catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        ...
    }

    return isPersisted;
}
```

When I run the tests I am seeing the following errors:

```
mockit.internal.MissingInvocation: Missing invocation of:
javax.persistence.EntityManager#contains(Object)
   with arguments: any Object
   on mock instance: javax.persistence.$Impl_EntityManager@44022631
    at at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    ... 4 more 
Caused by: Missing invocation
    at [redacted].dal.dao.SyncClaimDaoImplTest$1.<init>(SyncClaimDaoImplTest.java:48)
    at [redacted].dal.dao.SyncClaimDaoImplTest.testSaveEntity(SyncClaimDaoImplTest.java:46)
    at [redacted].dal.dao.SyncClaimDaoImplTest.testSaveClaim(SyncClaimDaoImplTest.java:67)
    ... 10 more
```

Now if I just move the Expectations block into the @Test method like so:

```java
@Test
public void testSaveClaim() {

    new Expectations() {
        {
            em.contains(any); result = true;
            em.merge(any);
        }
    };

    Assert.assertTrue(syncClaimDao.saveClaim(new SyncClaimEntity()));
```

I get a successful test run as should be.  I'm thinking that the [spring](/questions/tagged/spring) autowiring for the Test method is not properly scoping my Expectations.  That's why I'm seeing the missing invocation errors.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to generalize my Expectations so I can create simpler tests for generalized methods?

Comment: You should show the implementation of `SyncClaimDaoImpl`. But I see several problems in the code that was shown: 1) the `syncClaimDao` field should have the actual type that is meant to be tested, not the interface; 2) a `@Tested` field should not be assigned, as JMockit takes care of that; 3) `@Injectable` fields should not be explicitly assigned into the tested object, as JMockit also takes care of that; 4) if "save" functionality is generic, then it should be done through a general `save(Entity)` method declared in a base `Dao` type, not with specific methods like `saveClaim`.

Comment: @Rogério I went and added the SyncClaimDaoImpl.saveClaim implementation.  I can modify the syncClaimDao to map to the Impl instead of the interface.

The reason the save function is generic - is that I implemented it that way on the backend.  Our interface calls for specific save calls and not a generic method.  Theoretically if I test one, I can test all of them, but I now just trying to figure out how to generalize the Expectations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the mistake now: `T.isInstance(SyncClaimEntity.class)`. The `Class#isInstance(Object)` method is supposed to be called with *an instance* of the class, not with the class itself; so, it's always returning false because `SyncClaimEntity.class` is obviously not an instance of `SyncClaimEntity`.

Comment: Thanks, that was a simplistic mistake >.<  I suppose this can at least serve as an example of generalizing Expectations for future onlookers.